# MacVim - surround.vim - visual "cs" just deletes selection

Tags: vim, macvim

I have the MacPorts version of MacVim installed. My Vim configuration includes pathogen.vim and a Git clone of the latest version of surround.vim. When I open the `README.markdown` file from the surround.vim code, select `Hello World` inside of the `"`'s and try to type `cs"'`, the `c` keystroke just deletes `Hello World`.

Does anyone know why this is not working?

When I type `S"` while `Hello World` is highlighted it surrounds it just fine.  I've even tried making a new file - surrounding something and then changing what I surrounded - but it's simply not working. Every time I press `c` it just deletes everything highlighted.

Comment: Did you put the `pathogen#infect` call into your .vimrc file?

Comment: @BryanRoss Yes, This is the contents of my http://pastebin.com/fbkFYyHV

Comment: Ok, and you did `git clone` the surround.vim plugin into `$HOME/.vim/bundle`, right?

Comment: @BryanRoss yes, http://pastebin.com/FeDXqkr6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default behavior of the c word in vim is to "change" things. What you're telling vim when you highlight something and hit c is that you want to change it. It then deletes it and lets you type over it with new text. I imagine when you highlight, hit cs"' it puts an s"' where your word was?

**The answer**: Don't highlight it by selecting it all. Just put the cursor inside the quotes. It'll work just fine. :)

Comment: it works! - thanks ;)  ( I can't accept this answer for 3 minutes... ) - but it worked!